# Prevent HD from sleeping in USB external enclosure

Tags: usb, sleep

I have seen this asked several times. However none of the solutions proposed have worked for me. I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 with a Mediasonic HF2-SU3S2 ProBox filled with 4 x 2TB drives. Regardless of what I try, the drives become unresponsive after 20 minutes. Reboot and they are back.

I have tried adding these to cron:

```
*/15 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'dd if=/dev/disk/by-uuid/(unique ID) of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$R>
*/10 * * * * sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb1
*/5 * * * * /bin/touch /dev/sdb &>/dev/null
```

Also running this command
sudo hdparm -S 0 /dev/sdb

- Output: setting standby to 0 (off)

Still, after 20 minutes the drives become unavailable. Did I format any of the commands in cron improperly? Any other ideas? Oh, I should say, I am using /dev/sdb first and once I get that one drive to work, I will apply everything to the other 3 drives. Thank you.

Comment: hi! Hard to tell whether it's correctly formatted, the first (and probably most important) line got truncated. Also, I'd guess this line never actually triggers a second read – after the first one, the by in question would be in buffers, I'd guess.  Other than that, hm, "being unresponsive" is not the same as "going to sleep". What are the symptoms, *exactly*, of that?

Comment: What's the output of `dmesg` when the device becomes *unresponsive*? Anything in the logs?

Comment: Awesome. I will check some logs. By unresponsive I observe it as follows. I have several file shares or media repositories on these drives. If I access through SAMBA or through my Plex server, everything works after reboot, and then at 5, 15, 18 minutes. But if I request nothing of the server through SAMBA or PLEX for 20 minutes, then try, the share appears "empty" on all my client boxes and PLEX can't load the medai. I give these to examples as they are two different services.

Comment: So, the only difference between a share, mounted on a drive that I am accessing and a share, mounted on a drive a rest for over 20 minutes is this. Using SAMBA, if I keep a drive alive through touches, using this command "sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdb" reports "active/idle". When the contents of a share, through SAMBA dissapears, I run that command and the drive says "standby". Which is why I suspect some kind of power saving or sleeping.

Comment: Ok, So many, many errors. I'm not sure what to look for or report. Here is a very small portion that seems to relate when I tried to access a share mounted on this drive through SAMBA.

Comment: 118603.779076] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[118603.779099] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[118603.779100] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:a115] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[118603.779102] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr

Comment: [118647.350451] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:1044: inode #9699356: lblock 0: comm smbd: error -5 reading directory block
[118647.366663] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): __ext4_get_inode_loc_noinmem:4395: inode #87556120: block 350224417: comm smbd: unable to read itable block
[118648.668514] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[118649.081453] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): __ext4_find_entry:1635: inode #9699329: comm smbd: reading directory lblock 0